# Where do I get all Quickbooks XML to exchange data?

Tags: quickbooks

Where can I find all supported quickbooks xml format? basically I am trying to use Quickbook webconnector to exchange data between quickbook and my business application. I want to do automation as much as possible. I am using Quickbooks 2011 Enterprise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got link where I can find all supported format based on QB version.

https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Posting as answer with hope it help others.

Comment: Additionally, the qbXML version to QuickBooks version matrix can be found on page 17 of the SDK release notes: http://developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/ReleaseNotes.pdf